# VBA/Excel - Drill Down assigned to a button

Tags: vba, excel

Using Excel 2013 with PowerPivot, is it possible to create a command button to perform the "drill down" when clicked on? 
Working with some non technical customers and believe having clear buttons to press would help simplify the process for them.

Type of drill down I am referring to: https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Drill-into-PivotTable-data-c1b11240-fc8f-4fdd-a697-629bf6f7ee0b

Thanks in advance!

Comment: maybe I am missing something. But it seems to me that you asked a question and answered it yourself with the link to support.office.com yourself (yes, it is possible).

Comment: Microsoft has built in a couple ways to drill down, but they all involve clicking on a specific menu or a specific cell to make a submenu appear. When working with non technical people I have found it easier to make an actuall button that sits above the report that allows them to interact with the report/chart. in this case, it would be to drill down/up.

Comment: Why don't you just put a big text box on top of your sheet stating "double-click on a number to drill-down"?
If you want to offer drill-down functionality this is not only a matter of pressing a button but also knowing where / what to drill-down on. With a button on top of your sheet you wouldn't know what to drill-down on.

Comment: That would be one way, it would not allow you to drill up